# How to Properly Update Pivot table using added column as query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, relationship, pivot-table

I have this pivot table containing

imei status item_id

and here is my code

```
  $update = Item::find($item_id)->workArea()->wherePivot('imei', '=', 3)->first(); 
  $update->pivot->status = 'Sold';
  $update->pivot->save();

Before the function execute:
IMEI     STATUS     ITEM-ID
3        Available     3
5        Available     3

Result:
IMEI     STATUS     ITEM-ID
3        Sold          3
3        Sold          3

What I need:
IMEI     STATUS     ITEM-ID
3        Sold          3
5        Available     3
```

Here's my relationship

```
public function workArea()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('WorkArea','item_work-area','item_id','work-area_id')->withPivot('imei','status');
    }
```

here are the past conversation with other artisan
http://laravel.io/forum/07-08-2014-proper-chaining-for-my-pivot-table-to-execute-pivot-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in bugged with the current version 4.1

What I do is make a raw query instead of eloquent ORM,

```
 DB::table('item_work-area')
        ->where('imei', 11)
        ->update(array('status' => 'Sold'));
```

Hope this help for those who need to update their pivot table using added column as reference.

Comment: Ah ! since so long I am trying to do this and it's a bug ! thnx

Comment: Yes from Taylor itself :)